# Can you update your cypress.dev.config.ts file to exclude certain tests while running a Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, cypress

I have an application that runs Cypress e2e tests.  Most of the tests are pretty stable - as long as I run them locally.  When I run them by deploying to a dev environment through a Jenkins pipeline they get a lot less stable and inconsistent though.

I would like to exclude some of them when running the Jenkins pipeline while still running others.

Is there a way to update my cypress.dev.config.ts file such that it excludes certain tests while running them in the Jenkins pipeline?

This is a stripped down version of my cypress.dev.config.ts file so far.  Thanks.

```
import { defineConfig } from "cypress";

export default defineConfig({
  defaultCommandTimeout: 60000,
  execTimeout: 60000,
  pageLoadTimeout: 120000,
  taskTimeout: 60000,
  requestTimeout: 120000,
  responseTimeout: 120000,
  viewportWidth: 1600,
  viewportHeight: 1100,
  e2e: {
    env: {
      loginUrl: '',
      loginOrigin: ''
    }
  },
  reporter: 'junit',
  reporterOptions: {
    mochaFile: 'results/cypress-report-[hash].xml',
    jenkinsMode: true
  }
```

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm presuming `cypress.dev.config.ts` is fulfilling the role of `cypress.config.ts`, and that it's used for both the Jenkins run and `cypress open` run.

You could set a `CYPRESS_jenkins` env var when running under Jenkins, then use this code to change the [excludeSpecPattern](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#e2e)  configuration

> A String or Array of glob patterns used to ignore test files

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'cypress'

export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      if (config.env.jenkins) {
        config.excludeSpecPattern = [
          'do-not-run-me-in-jenkins.cy.ts',
        ]
      }
      return config
    },
  },

})
```